# Can I learn German upto b1 in 3 months

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

They tell me that they will make me to learn German upto b1 in 2.5 months

Comment: Hi, user30622, your question is unlikely to be answered in a way that can tell you whether **you** can do it. That’s why I’m voting to close.

Comment: I just want to say that I have seen this happen - a tutoring partner of mine started in December and managed to pass the Goethe B2 (!!) exam in March. But he didn't attend a formal class, limiting himself to self-study, and did basically nothing else but study German all day.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. There are plenty of references with estimates of the amount of the amount of formal study required for the various levels. For B1 these estimates are around 300-400 hours. Obviously some people are more or less talented than others and will need more or less time.

Comment: Has nothing to do with German. Average humans can learn all kinds of languages to a very good level in three months - provided they have nothing else to do, are really interested in the topic, have their physical needs (food, sleep, housing) cared for, and of course know how to learn and have users of that language around them. The problem is that hardly anyone has so much free time and dedication.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody here knows your learning circumstances, if you work/study something else besides your german courses and who "they" are, its hard to tell if *you* can learn it in 2.5 months.

However the [Goethe-Institut](https://www.goethe.de/en/spr/kup/prf/prf/gb1/inf.html) states that "candidates need to have completed between 350 and 650 45-minute units of teaching".
So if you attend a full-time german course during this 2.5 months it may theoretically be possible to pass the exam successfully afterwards.

Comment: “it may theoretically be possible”: Yes. Is it likely? No. I’ve known a few gifted people to whom secondary languages come naturally, but their results also included a lot of work and, most importantly, inclusion. Simply doing time in class will not yield significant results.

Comment: @Philipp I totally agree with you on this point, that's why I tried to keep the answer vague with the added "theoretically". I think it's at least very hard to learn a new language within three months without any prior knowledge.

Comment: One should also add that there's a theoretical and a practical B 1. Passing an exam doesn't mean the learner really knows all the things mentioned in the B 1 specifications.